# How to show the selected item name in the drop down list?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-select

I have created a  drop down list which is working perfectly fine, its fetching data from database and showing it in the drop-down list. The problem is that I am unable to identify that where to use 'selected'attribute in the select tag. Right now whatever the field I select it opens it, but in the drop down list it shows the first given name. I also tried to use 'selected' attribute, but it was showing the last item name in the drop-down list.

Kindly check it and guide me how to use 'selected' attribute in the loop.

```
    <?php
    //Drop Down List
    $sub_query = "select * from sub_categories where category_id=$category_id ";
    if (!$sub_query_run = mysql_query($sub_query))
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<select name='menu1' id='menu1' >
              <option  value='#'> All</option> ";
        while ($sub_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sub_query_run))
        {
        //$sub_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sub_query_run);
        $sub_category_id2 = $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_id'];
        $sub_category_name = $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_name'];
        echo "<option value='earings2.php?sub_category_id=$sub_category_id2' >"    
                .htmlspecialchars($sub_category_name= $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_name']).       
             "</option>";   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a condition for the selected item.

```
echo "<option value='earings2.php?sub_category_id=$sub_category_id2'";
if ($sub_category_id2 == $MATCHING_CATEGORY_ID) echo " selected";
echo ">".htmlspecialchars($sub_category_name= $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_name'])."</option>";
```

Where $MATCHING_CATEGORY_ID is the category id that will be selected.

Answer (score 3):

follow this example..

```
<select name="cate" id="cate" class="reginput" >
<option value="">Select Category</option>
<?php $s2="select * from tbl_category order by cate_name"; 
$q2=mysql_query($s2); 
while($rw2=mysql_fetch_array($q2)) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rw2['id']; ?>"<?php if($rw2['id']==$row['cate_id']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $rw2['cate_name']; ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="#" selected>ALL</option>
```

"selected" should be included in option tag

Comment: Yes, but when i add this in the loop, it shows the last selected item in the drop-down list.

Comment: @TahaKirmani That's because you'll add "selected" to **all** of your option tags.

Comment: In that you need to add a conditional statement.

Comment: eg: if(condition) {<option value="#" selected>All</option} else {<option value="#">Fav</option>}

Answer (score 1):

you need to use select in `<option>` tag

try this

```
while ($sub_query_fetch=    mysql_fetch_array($sub_query_run))
{
//$sub_query_fetch= mysql_fetch_array($sub_query_run);
$sub_category_id2=   $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_id'];
$sub_category_name= $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_name'];

$selected = ($isSelected == $sub_category_id2) ? 'selected' : ''; should be your selected condition fetch from db

echo "<option ".$selected."
value='earings2.php?sub_category_id=$sub_category_id2' >"
.htmlspecialchars($sub_category_name= $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_name']).       
"</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like,

```
// get the category id from request parameter
$sc_id=isset($_REQUEST['sub_category_id']) ? $_REQUEST['sub_category_id'] : "";
while ($sub_query_fetch=    mysql_fetch_array($sub_query_run))
{
    //$sub_query_fetch= mysql_fetch_array($sub_query_run);
    $sub_category_id2=   $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_id'];
    $sub_category_name= $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_name'];
    $sel='';
    if($sc_id==$sub_category_id2)// get the selected item
        $sel='selected="selected"';
    echo "<option value='earings2.php?sub_category_id=$sub_category_id2' ".$sel." >"
    .htmlspecialchars($sub_category_name= $sub_query_fetch['sub_category_name']).       
    "</option>";    
}
```